# Setting focus dynamically in first element of FormGroup

Tags: angular

I have a `FormArray` which contains `FormGroup` with multiple `Controls`.
And have a function which copies `FormGroup` fron `FormArray`'s index and pushes it in FormArray(duplicates FormArray).

After pushing I want to set focus at the first input element of the inserted `FormGroup`

my view html looks like

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let serviceForm of services.controls; let idx = index">
      <div class="row service-row" [formGroupName]="idx">
          
          <div class="requirement"><input type="text" formControlName="requirement" [attr.id]="'requirement_' + idx" (keyup.alt.ArrowDown)="copyService(idx)"/><span></span></div>
          ...
          ...
          <div class="service_status"><input type="text" formControlName="serviceStatus" readonly tabindex="-1" /><span></span></div>
          <div class="service_price"><input type="text" formControlName="servicePrice" readonly tabindex="-1" /><span></span></div>
          <div class="action"><span (click)="onResetService(idx)"><svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="./assets/symbol-defs.svg#icon-delete"></use></svg></span></div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
```

and the method which copies the `FormGroup` is

```
  copyService(idx: number) {
    const service = this.formService.copyService( idx - 1);

    if( !!service ) {
      this.services.setControl( idx , service);

    }
        
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById("requirement_" + idx)?.focus();
    })
    
  }
```

but I seems tobe ugly way to set focus. What should be the correct way to set focus?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom directive and move focus logic inside directive instead of using setTimeOut

**focus.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[appFocus]',
})
export class FocusDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.element.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<input type="text" [id]="i" formControlName="requirement" appFocus />
```

**[Sample Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kw7bmn?file=src/app/focus.directive.ts)**